# How do you get an angularjs service called x from a module B inside a module A that also owns a service named x?

Tags: angularjs

How do you get an angularjs service called x from a module B inside a module A that also owns a service named x? Here's the code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services'])
  .factory('foo', function() {
    return 42;
  });

angular.module('app.services', [])
  .factory('foo', function() {
    return 43;
  });

app.run(['foo', function(foo) {
  console.log("MyApp is running and `foo` is: " + foo);
}]);

angular.bootstrap(null, ['app']);
```

How do I get the`run` method to print `43`?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't.  Dependencies all share the same namespace so you will need to name your services with something like foo42 and foo43.

Comment: Really? Ridiculous! a DI container that does not allow namespacing? Thanks anyway

Comment: Of course it allows name spacing.  You just have to tell it somewhere what the names space is.  app.foo and app.services.foo will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `injector` using the dependant module and retrieve the service/factory.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['module1'])
.factory('test', function () {
  return '42'
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function (test, $injector) {
   console.log(test); // prints 42
   console.log(angular.injector(['module1']).get('test')) // prints 43
})

angular.module('module1', [])
.factory('test', function () {
  return '43'
})
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSUGCwtkD9gkv0sxbnSM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Angular modules do not provide true namespacing. You are dealing with a collision and will need to have `foo` named differently in each module.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services'])
  .factory('foo', function() {
    return 42;
  });

angular.module('app.services', [])
  .factory('svcFoo', function() {
    return 43;
  });

app.run(['svcFoo', function(foo) {
  console.log("MyApp is running and `foo` is: " + foo);
}]);

angular.bootstrap(null, ['app']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by injecting the module from which you need to use the factory. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n4tmtL3/) for a preview.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services'])
.factory('foo', function() {
    return 42;
});

angular
.module('app.services', [])
.factory('foo', function() {
    return 43;
});

app.run(['foo', function(foo) {
    var inj = angular.injector(['app.services']);
    var foo2 = inj.get('foo');
    console.log("MyApp is running and `foo` is: " + foo);
    console.log("MyApp injected `foo` is: " + foo2);
}]);

angular.bootstrap(null, ['app']);
```